# nodeclipse debugger configuration

Tags: eclipse, node.js, debugging, nodeclipse, nodemon

I have problem configuring nodeclipse properly for debugging.
I configured nodemon as my node monitor but it seams debbuger doesn't attach to my program but to nodemon.

console says :

```
/usr/local/bin/node --debug-brk=5858 /usr/lib/node_modules/nodemon/nodemon.js /myproject/server.js
```

Debugger stops at the first line of nodemon but doesn't seem to see my programs breakpoint.

Any ideas ? Alternatively, is there a way to run programs from neclipse without node monitor which seem to be always needed...

Comment: problem seem to be comming from my project. I created a new express project and it is behaving normally and desn't put nodemon.js in the middle... any idea why node monitor can get in the middle of my start line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in fact due to "corrupted" project.
I deleted the project and recreated a fresh one with my files.
All is working as expected now.

Hope it'll hep others.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also add that you're debugging nodemon there, rather than your script. If you pass the `--debug-brk=5858` to nodemon, rather than node, nodemon will spawn your script with debug enabled, and you'll be able to debug *your* script (instead of nodemon!).