# Nodeclipse debugger ignoring breakpoints

Tags: node.js, debugging, v8, nodeclipse, nodemon

I'm using Nodeclipse 0.10 with nodemon, but when I try to debug my script it doesn't stop at any of my breakpoints. I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111289/nodeclipse-debugging-wont-stop-at-breakpoints) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615332/nodeclipse-debugger-configuration) answer but it hasn't helped.

Occasionally, it will stop on the first line of nodemon, other times it gives me a timeout error from the V8 VM, and sometimes it doesn't do anything at all.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. I tried both the "Node application" and the "Node with monitor", neither one works.
2. Removed nodemon from the preferences page, but then Eclipse just complains it's missing the nodemon path and won't start my script (even if I select "Node application")
3. Ran `node --debug-brk=5858` from the command line and then tried to attach the Eclipse debugger to it
4. Tried launching the debug from the toolbar button (my personal default) as well as from context menu after right clicking the script file - that just makes it stop on the `module.exports` line of the script
5. Ran `eclipse --clean`

None of it works. As a side note, I did *not* install Nodeclipse into a new Eclipse environment when I installed it, because it took me a long time to configure my existing one to where I liked it, and I'd rather be able to keep that.

Anyone dealt with this issue before?

Comment: How did you configured nodemon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this was embarassingly stupid...somehow, "Skip all breakpoints" had become activated in the Run menu in Eclipse. It's working now.

Thanks everyone for the help though. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is already version 0.11, that has some [improvements](http://www.nodeclipse.org/history). You can try it within [Enide Studio 2014](http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/studio/2014/). But of course, it does not matter whether it is fresh new or updated Nodeclipse version.

You should have paid attention to Nodeclipse Console messages, especially when there are question. You would what actual `node` command is executing. And I guess there won't be `--debug-brk=5858`.

Right-click on the launched file, select Properties or press <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd>,
then if in Run/Debug Setting you see 2 or more Launch configuration, delete all or some. They are created automatically during first launch (with message in Nodeclipse Console)

I am currently Nodeclipse project lead, but I don't continue with nodemon support, as I am not using it. I would appreciate [feedback, research and suggestion](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/new) on how to improve that flow.

Comment: This is what the Nodeclipse console has to say: `/opt/nodejs/bin/node --debug-brk=5858 /home/chris/Programmieren/workspace/HelloWorld/app.js --tea-pot-mode`, so I think it is starting the debugger alright. Last night, I uninstalled all JDKs, installed the latest Oracle Java 7 JDK, then pulled a fresh install of Eclipse Kepler and Nodeclipse and it's _still_ not stopping on breakpoints (except the first one when using `debug-brk` instead of `debug`). I'm at a loss......

Comment: There is no need to uninstall JDK, just configure which one to use https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F
for small apps and `debug` option it is impossible to debug, because app can finish in 10ms, while debugger needs 100ms to connect. See F1 built-in or Online Help Debug page https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.help/contents/debug.md